UART works different when, receive function is executed and data is sent Vs data is sent and receive function is executed(debugMode)
I have been trying to understand UART communication and this is something I could not understand why it is happening.
Here is the code:
( I have not included all the initilization code here)

uint8_t rxData[10];

while (1)
  {
    
        HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, rxData, 4, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  
  }
 

I have added  a breakpoint at HAL_UART_Receive() to see what's happening.
This is the image showing the rxData before the function is executed:

Below image shows the function executed and the cpu is blocked for receiving data:

Once I  sent data using a serial monitor, this is the updated array:

If I do the same, like execute the function and then send the data, like 4567, the array is updated accordingly, like this:

But, here is the tricky part:
Now, if I try to send the data from the serial monitor and then execute the function, this is what it looks:
(Assume the array has 4567 already and run the code after clicking send(8901) in the serial monitor)
The function does not execute and I have to resend some other number, say 1234 and the array becomes like this:


Could anyone explain why is this happening?
I have tried understanding it from a register point of view and could not able to.
Here is the source code of the function:
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Receive(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
{
  uint8_t  *pdata8bits;
  uint16_t *pdata16bits;
  uint32_t tickstart = 0U;

  /* Check that a Rx process is not already ongoing */
  if (huart->RxState == HAL_UART_STATE_READY)
  {
    if ((pData == NULL) || (Size == 0U))
    {
      return  HAL_ERROR;
    }

    huart->ErrorCode = HAL_UART_ERROR_NONE;
    huart->RxState = HAL_UART_STATE_BUSY_RX;
    huart->ReceptionType = HAL_UART_RECEPTION_STANDARD;

    /* Init tickstart for timeout management */
    tickstart = HAL_GetTick();

    huart->RxXferSize = Size;
    huart->RxXferCount = Size;

    /* In case of 9bits/No Parity transfer, pRxData needs to be handled as a uint16_t pointer */
    if ((huart->Init.WordLength == UART_WORDLENGTH_9B) && (huart->Init.Parity == UART_PARITY_NONE))
    {
      pdata8bits  = NULL;
      pdata16bits = (uint16_t *) pData;
    }
    else
    {
      pdata8bits  = pData;
      pdata16bits = NULL;
    }

    /* Check the remain data to be received */
    while (huart->RxXferCount > 0U)
    {
      if (UART_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout(huart, UART_FLAG_RXNE, RESET, tickstart, Timeout) != HAL_OK)
      {
        huart->RxState = HAL_UART_STATE_READY;

        return HAL_TIMEOUT;
      }
      if (pdata8bits == NULL)
      {
        *pdata16bits = (uint16_t)(huart->Instance->DR & 0x01FF);
        pdata16bits++;
      }
      else
      {
        if ((huart->Init.WordLength == UART_WORDLENGTH_9B) || ((huart->Init.WordLength == UART_WORDLENGTH_8B) && (huart->Init.Parity == UART_PARITY_NONE)))
        {
          *pdata8bits = (uint8_t)(huart->Instance->DR & (uint8_t)0x00FF);
        }
        else
        {
          *pdata8bits = (uint8_t)(huart->Instance->DR & (uint8_t)0x007F);
        }
        pdata8bits++;
      }
      huart->RxXferCount--;
    }

    /* At end of Rx process, restore huart->RxState to Ready */
    huart->RxState = HAL_UART_STATE_READY;

    return HAL_OK;
  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_BUSY;
  }
}


Is the source code of HAL_UART_Receive() available? If so, please [edit] your question and add it. And a link to the user manual of your specific MCU, please.

You will probably have to re-write most of the text. It's totally unclear what you do and what happens. "...if I try to send the data from the serial monitor and then execute the function..." - what function? The HAL receive? Did you just say you tried to receive something before calling the receive function? In that case, it wouldn't work. You can't receive anything at all without calling a receive function first.

This is the link for MCU manual:
https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0368-stm32f401xbc-and-stm32f401xde-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

The UART on the STM32 does not have a buffer. (It can maybe buffer a single character in the receive data register.)
If you send 8901 to the STM32 when you are not actively receiving on the UART, the 8 will enter the receive data register, and then the 901 will simply be thrown away.
If you then call HAL_UART_Receive() and send 1234, you will get the buffered 8 from the first transmit, and the 123 from the second transmit.

Could you explain the Dataflow in the different registers for UART?

@Theja it's very well documented in the datasheet. I would also recommend sending/recieving through interrupts or DMA instead.

As soon as the data is received into the DR register, RXNE bit is set. Will the HAL_UART_Receive() clears the RXNE flag once it read the data from DR?

"you are not actively receiving on the UART" - What does it mean that it is actively receiving?

@Theja It means removing characters from the receive data register so that it becomes free to receive more characters. If you don't do that, it will just continue to contain the first character, and subsequent characters will be dropped.

As soon as the data is received into the DR register, RXNE bit is set. Will the HAL_UART_Receive() clears the RXNE flag once it read the data from DR?
Could you help me on this?

@Theja The act of reading the DR register will automatically clear the RXNE bit.

Understood! But here is something I have posted again regarding UART.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78579807/hal-uart-receive-function-is-not-writing-the-data-to-rxdata-properly
Could you please take a  look at it?

This is because the UART peripheral works independently of the MCU. When the serial port tool sends 8901, the program does not read out the 8 in time, so the following 901 will be discarded. When you re-run the program, the first data read out will be 8, followed by 123. So in order to avoid errors, you should read the empty BUFF when initializing UART.

Does not read 8 in time?

Yes, although your program is not running, your UART is still working (assuming that the MCU is not powered off and the UART will keep your last configuration). The 8901 sent by the UART can be received by the UART. However, after receiving the 8, the MCU does not read the BUFF, and the UART will discard the subsequent 901. You can try to read the empty BUFF when initializing the UART.
