HAL_UART_receive function is not writing the data to rxData[] properly
When I try sending 4 digits from serial monitor to UART using HAL_UART_Receive() , the array looks like image shown below.


Now that 1234 is stored in an array, if I re-execute the code, to write to the same array, say 1465 , the array now looks totally different something like this:

Here is the code:
uint8_t rxData[10];
while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      
          HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, rxData, 4, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, SET);
      HAL_Delay(500);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, RESET);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, rxData, 4,1000);
    

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

I have tried to reset and start again, yet it still shows the same.

It looks like you didn't just send 1234. You hit Enter on your keyboard, which sent a carriage-return (ASCII code 13) too.

How do I stop sending the carriage-return?

Don't press the Enter key on your keyboard? You may need to switch off line-buffered mode in your terminal, if it waits on you hitting Enter before sending anything.

When using the receive function HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, rxData, 4, HAL_MAX_DELAY);, which receives 4 bytes, if you input "1234" and press enter, the actual input from the terminal is "1234\r" (where \r is the carriage return). The HAL receive function only captures the first four bytes, so the carriage return \r will be processed as the first byte in the next iteration. Therefore, when you provide input for the second time, the carriage return \r from the previous input is stored in rxData[0], and the next three bytes are from your second input.
iteration -1
rxData[0] = '1'
rxData[1] = '2'
rxData[2] = '3'
rxData[3] = '4'

The carriage return \r will be stored in rxData[0] (in the 2nd iteration), and the HAL receive function will wait for the next 3 bytes. Once these bytes are received, they will be transmitted to the terminal.
iteration - 2
rxData[0] = '\r'
rxData[1] = '1'
rxData[2] = '4'
rxData[3] = '6'

iteration - 3
rxData[0] = '5'  
rxData[1] = byte1 of 3rd iteration    
rxData[2] = byte2 of 3rd iteration    
rxData[3] = byte3 of 3rd iteration

